# Build code in new cpp file in a cloned repository

Tags: github, visual-c++, build, repository

I'm experimenting with working with github in microsoft visual studio 2022. I've have cloned an empty repository from my github and I add a new cpp file to it, I've also pushed it to my repository yet somehow, I can't build nor run it. It told me to select a valid startup item.
I think it might be because it doesn't have anything to build? I don't really know at this point

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.